# Switch/case in mvc action but I have nothing to return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get the error, that the action doesn't return something in any path.

What would you do, what meaningful could I return? Throw an exception?

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName(string actionMode, MyViewModel vm)
{
    switch (actionMode)
    {
        case "yes":
            return RedirectToAction("actionName1");

        case "no":
            return RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = vm.data });
    }
}
```

Comment: You missing the parameter name for `MyViewModel` - (assume its a typo?). And `new { data = MyViewModel.data })` would not work unless you have a static property

Comment: was a typo its corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName(string actionMode, MyViewModel)
{
    return actionMode == "yes" ? RedirectToAction("actionName1") : RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = MyViewModel.data });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your logic is a boolean operation then why not do this?

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName(string actionMode, MyViewModel)
{
    if (actionMode == "yes")
        return RedirectToAction("actionName1");

    return RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = MyViewModel.data });
}
```

Alternatively, you could throw an exception after the switch statement.

`throw new InvalidOperationException();`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code as well :-

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName(string actionMode, MyViewModel)
{
    switch (actionMode)
    {
        case "yes":
            return RedirectToAction("actionName1");
        default:
            return RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = MyViewModel.data });
    }
}
```

default will execute when no conditions match.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error in `switch` because you didn't handle another string values could pass. You can fix it if you specify default behavior like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName(string actionMode, MyViewModel)
{
    switch (actionMode)
    {
        case "yes":
            return RedirectToAction("actionName1");

        case "no":
            return RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = MyViewModel.data });
        default:
            goto case "yes"; // yes behavior by default
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
default:
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("only 'yes' or 'no' parameter value allowed"); // exception for another values
```

Another solution is to force your form to pass "True" or "False" values instead of "yes" or "no", and bind it to bool parameter, and use `if` operator instead of `switch`:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName([Bind(Prefix = "actionMode")]bool isYesActionMode, MyViewModel)
// Bind attribute used to get value from old parameter name
{
    if (isYesActionMode)
        return RedirectToAction("actionName1");

    return RedirectToAction("actionName2", new { data = MyViewModel.data });
}
```